# removeFromParentNode gets called unexpectedly

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm doing a little application using Swift and SceneKit and I just noticed something very strange. If I subclass SCNNode and I add that object to scene, removeFromParentNode gets called but does not remove node from scene, it just executes additional code from overriding. Can someone explain why this is happen? I'm using xcode 7 beta 4 with El Capitan beta 5

Answer (score 1):

when overriding `removeFromParentNode` you must call `super.removeFromParentNode()` otherwise the code for the default behaviour (removing the node) is not executed.